# MATLAB filename separation

Tags: matlab, split

In filename "`name`" like `'10_m1_m2_const_m1_waves_20_90_m2_waves_90_20_20200312_213048'` I need to separate
`'10_m1_m2_const_m1_waves_20_90_m2_waves_90_20'` from `'20200312_213048'`

```
name_sep = split(name,"_");
sep = '_';
name_join=[name_sep{1,1} sep name_sep{2,1} sep .....];
```

is not working, because a number of "_" are variable.

So I need to move a file:

```
movefile([confpath,name(without 20200312_213048),'.config'],[name(without 20200312_213048), filesep, name, '.config']);
```

Do you have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: How to identify the right place to cut? Is it always the 12th `_`? Is the tail always of the pattern <number>_<number>? I am sure regular expressions will work, but first we have to understand the pattern.

Comment: How about finding the second to last underscore? Would that work? How do you define the place where to cut?

Comment: @Daniel no, this is the Problem. Sometimes it calls like '1_m1_waves_20_90_20200311_203018' so its variable

Comment: @Chris Luengo but how? the Part "20200312_213048" has allways the same format: YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS  
How do you define the place where to cut? - its a second underline "_" before end

Answer (score 2):

- Maybe you can try `regexp` to find the starting position for the separation:

```
ind = regexp(name,'_\d+_\d+$');
name1 = name(1:ind-1);
name2 = name(ind+1:end);
```

such that

```
name1 = 10_m1_m2_const_m1_waves_20_90_m2_waves_90_20
name2 = 20200312_213048
```

- Or the code below with option `tokens`:

```
name_sep = cell2mat(regexp(name,'(.*)_(\d+_\d+$)','tokens','match'));
```

which gives

```
name_sep =
{
  [1,1] = 10_m1_m2_const_m1_waves_20_90_m2_waves_90_20
  [1,2] = 20200312_213048
}
```

Comment: @Fracture You're welcome! If you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strfind`. Either if you have a key that is always present before or after the point where you want to split the name:

```
nm = '10_m1_m2_const_m1_waves_20_90_m2_waves_90_20_20200312_213048';

key = 'waves_90_20_';
idx = strfind(nm,key) + length(key);
nm(idx:end)
```

Or if you know how may `_` are in the part that you want to have:

```
idx = strfind(nm,'_');
nm(idx(end-2)+1:end)
```

In both cases, the result is:

> '20_20200312_213048'

Comment: Thank you! I can use a second part =)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the timestamp is always at the end of the string, you can use [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) and count backwards from the end of the string:

```
name = '10_m1_m2_const_m1_waves_20_90_m2_waves_90_20_20200312_213048';
udscr = strfind(name,'_');
name_date = name(udscr(end-1)+1:end)
name_meta = name(1:udscr(end-1)-1)

name_date =

    '20200312_213048'

name_meta =

    '10_m1_m2_const_m1_waves_20_90_m2_waves_90_20'
```